Is it possible to implement an autosave feature in GoogleAppsScript that also saves active cells/the cell being edited when the function is triggered
before  after  As mentioned in the title, I'm looking for a way to automatically save a sheet while it's still being edited. I want every single change, even as you're typing, to be saved immediately. For example, if a small change occurs, it should be automatically saved. Essentially, I want a button that, when triggered, saves the cell that's currently being edited, even if the editing process is not yet complete.
I tried creating a duplicate sheet to check if it's saved, but that didn't work. I also attempted to change the active selection from the editing cell to another one, thinking it would automatically exit the editing mode and save, but it still doesn't work.

Not possible, AFAIK.

You'd probably have to create a browser extension to capture individual keypresses during an edit. Google Sheets saves all changes automatically. An incomplete edit isn't considered a change in this context.

"You'd probably have to create a browser extension to capture individual keypresses during an edit" how to make this?  @doubleunary


Is it possible to implement an autosave feature in GoogleAppsScript that also saves active cells/the cell being edited when the function is triggered

The answer is no. There are no Apps Script triggers that fire while you are editing a cell.

The "on edit" event fires after a cell edit is complete.

The "on change" event fires after another kind of change happens.

See Automation triggers and events for more.


You could create a browser extension that captures individual keypresses during an edit, but that cannot be done in Apps Script, and it would take some actual programming.

"You could create a browser extension that captures individual keypresses during an edit," do you mean add-on or literal browser extension? if so how to make something like that?

It would have to be a browser extension.

You asked "Is it possible to implement an autosave feature in GoogleAppsScript". The answer is no. I gather that this is your first question at Stack Overflow. See What should I do when someone answers my question?

"how to make something like that?" — that is a different question that will require a different solution. Please ask only one question per post. Post a new question instead.
